# Calculate webform total from select list fields

Tags: 7, webforms

Like e.g. there are two select options type components that has various amounts of $ to select from. So if user selects in one field $100 and $200 then the next field below it would generate the total which would be $300 in this example.

I did research, and the module Webform Calculation Components does the exact thing I want, but it does that only with numeric fields where user has to type amounts manually. So it's a no-go. In my case user has to select from drop-down list already given amounts.

Cheers

Comment: Does the values have specific increment like 100,200,300? or they can be in any manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Webform Calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator) module for your purpose.

This module provides a formula webform component for computed values, where you can enter a mathematical calculation based on the other fields. E.g. Create a formula field with value formkey1 * 0.1 * formkey2.

Let us know incase of any concern/query regarding this.

Thanks!